# Spring MVC and @Async

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, asynchronous

I have a long running Service method (doing business logic) and I would like the client to return immediately after submitting the request to the Controller. I would like the client to poll periodically to see if the Service method has completed execution.
After reading through these two links :
[link1](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/08/spring-asynchronous-support/) 
[link2](http://groovyjavathoughts.blogspot.com/2010/01/asynchronous-code-with-spring-3-simple.html)
I am convinced that `@Async` is the right approach for my situation. My question is which, the Service method or the Controller method should have the `@Async` annotation. And how exactly will the `Controller` method have reference to a Future object so that it can invoke its `get()` or `isDone()` methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the @Async on a service method that calls the "real" service method.  That way you have two ways of calling it, async and non-async.

Have the controller method store the Future returned by the service in the Session and then return.  Then the when the client polls the controller (on a different URL/method) the controller can get the Future out of the session and call isDone() on it.

Comment: How do you properly deal with `Future` not being serializable?